# Formulario de editar no me funciona al realizar una peticion ajax javascrip

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Tengo mi formulario normal de insertar y ahí mis 2 campos de `select` si me funcionan correctamente, el problema es cuando voy al botón editar que me lleva a otra pantalla junto con el `id`. Ahí ya no me funciona mi formulario al realizar la misma petición `ajax`, no me encuentra la ruta. No se si es que tiene que ver el id que me toma a la hora de darle editar.

Estos son mis dos `select`, que en el formulario insertar si me funcionan correctamente. El problema es a la hora de darle editar en un `datatablas` de jquery, selecciono el campo que quiero editar y me toma el `id` y me lleva a la pantalla con los datos, pero los campos dinámicos que tengo no me funcionan y a la hora de ver lo que me traen me tira un error 404 donde me dice que no encuentra la ruta.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('departa', 'Departamento:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-lg-10">
 {!! Form::select('departamento',$departamento_honduras,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'departamento_dinamico']) !!}
           </div>
           </div>
           <br>
           <br>

           <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('munic', 'Municipio:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
         <div class="col-lg-10">
         {!! Form::select('municipios',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'municipio_dinamico']) !!}
        </div>
        </div>








$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select[name="departamento"]').on('change', function(){
        var id_departamento = $(this).val();
        if(id_departamento) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/municipios_dinamico/'+id_departamento,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {

                    $('select[name="municipio"]').empty();

                    $.each(data, function(idx, municipio){

                        $('select[name="municipio"]').append('<option value="'+ municipio.id +'">' + municipio.nombre + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="municipio_id"]').empty();
        }

    });

});
```

Esta es la ruta que no encuentra

```
Route::get('municipios_dinamico/{id}',[
    'as'=>'municipios_dinamico',
    'uses'=>'icf@municipio_dinamico_get'
]);
```

Esta es mi función donde no entra

```
 public static function municipio_dinamico_get(Request $request,$id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            $municipios=municipios::municipios_dinamico($id);
            return response()->json($municipios);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor deja de ponerle negrita (bold) a todos los textos de tus preguntas, no es necesario y además molesta un poco la lectura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo el Ajax por aquí en principio lo demas lo veo correctamente

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('select[name="departamento"]').on('change', function(){
         var id_departamento = $(this).val();
         if(id_departamento) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/municipios/'+id_departamento,
                 type:"GET",
                 dataType:"json",
                 success:function(data) {

                     $('select[name="municipio_id"]').empty();

                     $.each(data, function(idx, municipio){

                         $('select[name="municipio_id"]').append('<option value="'+ municipio.id +'">' + municipio.nombre + '</option>');

                     });
                 },
                 complete: function(){
                     $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                 }
             });
         } else {
             $('select[name="municipio_id"]').empty();
         }

     });

 });
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias lo intente hacer de la forma que me indicaste pero me sigue con el mismo problema no me encuentra la ruta me tira el error 404

Comment: lo actualice pero me sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: Buenas intenta adaptarlo a tu ejemplo, yo el que puse por ejemplo llama al name y tu solo tienes el id en el input

Comment: ya lo arregle muchas gracias por tu apoyo solo tenia que agregarle un / ala ruta